# How to provide a context for a Ember route callback

Tags: ember.js

Newbie Alarm!

I have a little master/detail view: http://jsbin.com/ijicor/112/edit

In the callback functions for connectOutlets and serialize the context is always undefined. What do I miss and how can I access the member data?

Comment: Similar to you, please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691667/action-link-with-transitionto-using-relationship-id.

Comment: I dont think this is the problem I have. I do not understand why the context is undefined in my example. In the example of the router primer (http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/#toc_implement-serialize-and-deserialize) the context is filled with the dynamic uri part (id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do 2 things. In line 11 I had to provide event as a parameter: 
  router.transitionTo('member', event);
and so the connectOutlets function does not receive a context but an event as parmeter. I found this out with a debugger and think the documentation is wrong here.

Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/ijicor/122/edit